# Should we connect to AWS SNS every time we send a push notification?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I am working on DJANGO server, creating a REST service. The purpose of the service is to send a push notification to the phone number mentioned in the request. I am using AWS SNS service for push notifications. I am establishing connection between my server and AWS every time there is a request to the server. My question is, can we establish a connection once the server is up, like opening a port as we do in a chat application? Or I should establish a connection every time?

I am using Boto package and below is my code

connection = SNSConnection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY,AWS_SECRET_KEY)
   connection.publish(message=jsonMessage, subject=title, target_arn=endPoint, message_structure=structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Client classes in the AWS SDK are just wrappers around other lower-level HTTP clients that interface with the HTTP REST methods of the AWS APIs. They are very light-weight so instantiating and destroying a Client instance on each HTTP request to your DJANGO app should be just fine -- you will incur little overhead. I wouldn't worry about shared state clients like you might utilize in Java or other multi-threaded application designs.

Comment: Thanks for the response